# Double integral bounds problem

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $$A =  \int_{0}^{1} e^{-t^2}dt $$ and $$B = \int_{0}^{1/2} e^{-t^2} dt $$

I have to evaluate the iterated integral
$ I = \int_{-1/2}^{1} \int_{0}^{x} e^{-y^2} dy dx$ In terms of A and B.

Also, i know (from the exercise) that there is two integers $m$ and $n$ such that
$$ I = mA - nB + e^{-1} - e^{-1/4}. $$

I tried to evaluate the inner integral but it ended up in a error function. I think that all i have to do is manipulate the integral bond, but im not very certain about how to do it. I need some ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Well, there is a standard here which requires that one show their work. You say you tried to evaluate the inner integral...can you post your work? I'm just trying to be consistent across the board (arithmetic, calculus, real analysis, algebraic geometry....etc) in terms of the site's "show your work" policy enforced on some, but not others.

Comment: I tried it by normal substitution, calling u=-y^2 and making some other changes, i got to a point that i didn't knew how to proceed, so i searched the internet and found that this is an special integral called error function. So i started to think about the bonds of integration but im not sure on how i should change tem in order to rewrite it in terms of the given integrals A and B. Sorry for any inconvenience i might have caused

Comment: No worries, No inconvenience. @Dovah. It simply helps us all when we have an idea what you've tried, etc. I appreciate your comment!

Comment: When you refer to manipulating the "integral bond", do you mean the "integral bound(s)"?

Comment: @amWhy yeah, that was a typing mistake

Answer (score 1):

You need to transpose the order of integration.

Your region is bounded by the lines $y = 0, y=x, x = - \frac 12, x = 1$

So we plot that out on a piece of paper, and we see that we really have two triangular regions.  And one of those is negative!

So how do we represent this in terms with x in terms of y?

I think the simplest way is to break it in two.

$-\int_{-\frac 12}^{0}\int_{-\frac 12}^y e^{-y^2} dx dy + \int_{0}^{1}\int_{y}^1 e^{-y^2} dx dy$

Update

$-\int_{-\frac 12}^{0}(y-\frac 12) e^{-y^2} dy + \int_{0}^{1}(1-y) e^{-y^2}dy\\
-\int_{-\frac 12}^{1}y e^{-y^2} dy +\frac 12\int_{-\frac 12}^{0}e^{-y^2}dy+ \int_{0}^{1}e^{-y^2}dy\\
\frac12 \int_{-\frac 12}^{0}e^{-y^2}dy+ \int_{0}^{1}e^{-y^2}dy = A+\frac 12B\\
A+B-\int_{-\frac 12}^{1}y e^{-y^2} dy\\
u=y^2, du = 2y \;dy\\
A+\frac 12 B - \frac 12\int_{\frac 14}^{1}e^{-u} du\\
A+\frac 12 B + \frac 12 (e^{-1} - e^{\frac 14})$

Comment: I dont get it: why should transpose the order of integration? I doesn't seem like the first thing one would think in front of this question. Is there any particular reason or it is just a "shortcut" to get to the answer? Thanks!

Comment: As you have already discovered integrating $\int e^{-y^2} dy$ is problematic. But $\int ye^{-y^2} dy$ we can tackle with a $u$-substitution.

Comment: how can the integral of ye^y can help me in this case?

Comment: @Dovah-king I finished the work.  Can you follow this?